# Using COM component fails as admin

Tags: c#, com, registry, registrykey

I have a .NET wrapper over a native dll.
I try to register the component only for current user based on this : [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3505/RegSvrEx-An-Enchanced-COM-Server-Registration-Util)
This runs fine, except if I right click the executable and say "Run as admin.." the tool will fail that it cannot find the class.

This is the code I use, is there something I am missing , I think it might be related to : 
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756926.aspx)

Thanks!

```
public int Register(ServerAction Action, string ServerName)
    {
        int hr = 0;
        string szFunction = (Action == ServerAction.Register) ? "DllRegisterServer" : "DllUnregisterServer";

        logger.Info("FileReader->Try to " + szFunction + " " + ServerName);
        try
        {
            IntPtr hMod = LoadLibrary(ServerName);

            if (hMod.ToInt32() != 0)
            {
                IntPtr registerDllServer_ProcAddress = GetProcAddress(hMod, szFunction);
                DllRegisterServerInvoker pfnDllProc = (DllRegisterServerInvoker)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(registerDllServer_ProcAddress, typeof(DllRegisterServerInvoker));
                if (pfnDllProc != null)
                {
                    if (isUserAdminAndProcessElevated())
                    {
                        logger.Info("User is admin and process is elevated!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        logger.Info("User is not admin!");
                        hr = OverrideClassesRoot(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\Classes");
                    }

                }


                hr = pfnDllProc();

                pfnDllProc = null;

                FreeLibrary(hMod);
            }
            else
            {
                hr = this.GetHresultFromWin32();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FileReader->" + szFunction + " " + ServerName + " FAILED!");
        }

        string errorMessage = new Win32Exception(hr).Message;
        logger.Fatal(errorMessage);
        return hr;
    }

    private Int32 OverrideClassesRoot(UIntPtr hKeyBase, string OverrideKey)
    {
        UIntPtr hkey = new UIntPtr();
        int l = RegOpenKeyA(hKeyBase, OverrideKey, ref hkey);

        if (l == 0)
        {
            l = RegOverridePredefKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, hkey);
            RegCloseKey(hkey);
        }

        return this.GetHresultFromWin32();
    }
```

Still haven't figured this out but I fixed it with : [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms973913.aspx)

Comment: Pretty unclear what "fail" looks like.  Just use SysInternals' Process Monitor.  Use it first with your program so you can see what keys are being written.  And again with the "tool" so you can see what keys it looks for.

Comment: Could you be more precise about what you want to happen, and what's happening instead? From your post and your code it's hard to see what's wrong. The code seems to only register the component if the program is _not_ run as admin, so it doesn't seem surprising that then when run as admin, the program would not find the component registered. I feel like I must be missing something, and some clarification could help.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Sorry for the slow reply, my use case is this. I have a C# tool that can be in multiple places on the user machine. On the same folder as the tool we have a COM dll(third party). My requirement is that when the tool starts it shall register the dll, and unregister when it finishes. This seems to work fine if the user has no admin rights, running as admin with UAC on the tool cannot find the registered dll.

Comment: @HansPassant I have looked with ProcMon the difference is that as admin the tool witll look in HKCU\... and fail, and then try in HKCR and succeed! Even if in ProcMon it says success when trying to use the DLL it will fail with class not found.

Comment: @TomaC: "the tool cannot find the registered dll". So the tool can find the DLL to _register_ it, but cannot find the DLL when it comes time to _unregister_ it (i.e. when the tool is exiting)?

Comment: @PeterDuniho The tool will fail with "Cannot find class with GUI...." before it even reach the Unregister part. So running the tool as user works fine but then running the tool as admin right after it will fail. Could be that the unregister it is not working correctly, I will check.